# RealVNC viewer cannot currently show the desktop (RASPBERRY PI4)

Tags: raspberry-pi, realvnc

I tried everything, changing resolution, forcing HDMI output, pi auto login. Nothing seems to work. Using Raspberry Pi 4. (Version 11.3, bullseye 64bit OS)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem for the last year with bullseye and couldnt find a solution to it till just now.

https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/5060068870813-Disabling-direct-capture-on-Raspberry-Pi-using-the-command-line

"The "direct capture" option is not working when running VNC Server on Raspberry Pi OS with the KMS driver (vc4-kms-v3d). The Fake KMS driver (vc4-fkms-v3d) is not affected."

```
sudo sed -i '/CaptureTech/d' /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11
sudo vncserver-x11 -service -reload
```

solved the problem for me to at least enable the VNC again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of Raspberry Pi OS you should be able to enable VNC and set a resolution for headless VNC connections via `raspi-config`. If that does not work then you seem to have broken something by experimenting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).